# Transferring the Google Maps API V3 "styles" to OpenLayers using ol3gm

Tags: html, ol3-google-maps

I have a map made with the google maps api v3, that has the style that I want. But I have no idea how to implement it (if at all possible) into OpenLayers. I will add the code that I wish to add to open layers below. I saw ol3gmp and hoped it was the answer but I can't figure out if it is or isn't.

```html
         styles:[
     {"elementType": "geometry","stylers": [{"color": "#242f3e"}]},
   {"elementType": "labels","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
   {"elementType": "labels.text.fill","stylers": [{"color": "#746855"}]},
     {"elementType": "labels.text.stroke","stylers": [{"color": "#242f3e"}]},
     {"featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
    {"featureType": "administrative.locality","elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]},
   {"featureType": "administrative.locality",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#d59563"}]},
     {"featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi","elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#d59563"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#263c3f"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]},
   {"featureType": "poi.park","elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]},
   {"featureType": "road","stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]},
   {"featureType": "road","elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#38414e"}]},
   {"featureType": "road","elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#212a37"}]},
   {"featureType": "road","elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#9ca5b3"}]},
   {"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#746855"}]},
   {"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#1f2835"}]},
   {"featureType": "road.highway","elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#f3d19c"}]},
   {"featureType": "transit","stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
   {"featureType": "transit.station.airport",
    "stylers": [{"visibility": "on"}]},
   {"featureType": "water","elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#17263c"}]},
   {"featureType": "water","elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#515c6d"}]},
   {"featureType": "water","elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
    "stylers": [{"color": "#17263c"}]}
   ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the style definition to the olgm layer and it will transfert it to the map created within Google Maps.  Here's a snippet:

```
var themedLayer = new olgm.layer.Google({
  styles: [{
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": -100
    },{
       "gamma": 2.25
    }]
  }]
});
```

See also this [live example](http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/dist/examples/themed.html) showing this (and its [JavaScript](http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/examples/dist/examples/themed.js) source file).

Comment: The JavaScript link is empty :S 

So if I understand you correctly, I put in the different "style elements" from google maps in to there?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: olgm is not defined
    at Test_2.html:30

Comment: That is the error I get now, when I add my "styles" in as shown above.

Comment: I fixed the JavaScript source file link.  About the ReferenceError: did you load olgm?  Take a look at the source code of the live example (at the html) to see how the libs are loaded.

Comment: I may be crazy, but I can't for the life of me find the libraries... Any help?

Comment: http://mapgears.github.io/ol3-google-maps/ (.zip icon on the right), or https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps/releases (the .zip files next to the release you want)